# Use quorum queue of RqbbitMQ in abp framework

Tags: abp

In the ABP framework, how to use the quorum queue of RabbitMQ?

I added a class that implements the IRabbitMqMessageConsumerFactory interface, like below, but it doesn't work.

Is there anything else I can try?

```
[ExposeServices(typeof(IRabbitMqMessageConsumerFactory))]
[Dependency(ReplaceServices = true)]
public class RabbitMqQuorumMessageConsumerFactory : RabbitMqMessageConsumerFactory
{
    public RabbitMqQuorumMessageConsumerFactory(IServiceScopeFactory serviceScopeFactory) : base(
        serviceScopeFactory)
    {

    }

    public new IRabbitMqMessageConsumer Create(
        ExchangeDeclareConfiguration exchange,
        QueueDeclareConfiguration queue,
        string connectionName = null)
    {
        const string quorumQueueType = "quorum";
        const string queueTypeName = "x-queue-type";
        var consumer = ServiceScope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<RabbitMqMessageConsumer>();
        if (queue.Arguments.ContainsKey(queueTypeName))
        {
            queue.Arguments.Remove(queueTypeName);
        }

        queue.Arguments.Add(queueTypeName, quorumQueueType);
        consumer.Initialize(exchange, queue, connectionName);
        return consumer;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to use the quorum queues, you'll need to cluster multiple nodes (at least 3) together. More info on the clustering can be found here:
https://www.rabbitmq.com/clustering.html.

On the quorum queue page of RabbitMQ it also shows how many nodes you need for a specific fault tolerance (https://www.rabbitmq.com/quorum-queues.html):
[image]

So it isn't just setting the `x-queue-type` to quorum, but actually connecting multiple nodes/machines together.

If you want to understand more about how quorum queues work, I'd suggest reading this link: https://www.cloudamqp.com/blog/quorum-queues-internals-a-deep-dive.html. It explains more about how the quorum queues actually work and how the Raft Consensus Algorithm works which RabbitMQ uses for Quorum Queues.

This is just a suggestion, but since you want to use quorum queues, it seems like you don't want to lose any messages. So I would take a look at [Durable Queues](https://www.rabbitmq.com/queues.html#durability) and [Persistent Messages](https://www.rabbitmq.com/persistence-conf.html)

Comment: Thanks for you help. Yes, I have a cluster of 3 nodes. I added log in the above code and it doesn't give any output, So I think it should be a problem with the code, not the rabbitmq cluster. May be I'm not clear on this part of the abp framework yet.

Comment: No worries, I don't have any experience on the abp framework, so I can't help you with that unfortunately. But it does indeed sound like the problem is there somewhere. Good luck!